# How do we know there doesn't exist an anomaly that implies that there is no good choice of dimension for the bosonic string?

Tags: string-theory, quantum-anomalies

By considering $\langle T^\alpha_\alpha\rangle$, the Weyl anomaly, we can show that the critical dimension, $D=26$ is the only possible choice of dimension for the bosonic string.

However, how do we know we can stop there? How do we know there doesn't exist a similar anomaly, that perhaps gives us a different critical dimension - in which case there is no choice of $D$ which is does not give some anomaly?

Comment: A good question. The anomaly is a phenomena of nonconservation on the quantum level of a classically conserved current. It seems to me, that the conserved currents in the bosonic are given by the Virasoro generators. Are they the only conserved charges in the theory?

Comment: There is some issue with this question I think (the question itself I am in no way able to answer) that doesn't warrant reporting, but you should avoid asking the proof of a negative. Asking to be sure there isn't a contradiction to some theory, is equivalent (though less extreme perhaps) than say asking to prove god's nonexistence. Possibly this question is more nuanced than I am qualified to comment on though and this is entirely reasonable

Answer (score 0):

Anomalies arise as the quantum nonconservation of a classical symmetry. **The answer to your question is simply that the only classical symmetries of the Polyakov action are the diffeomorphism and Weyl ones.**

It may be the case that bosonic string theory could develop an anomaly after quantization, but that is actually not the case; your favourite way to quantize the classical Polyakov action (cannonical/light-cone/Gupta-Bleuler/BRST) is the proof that the latter is actually not the case. No anomalus quantum symmetries are developed after quantization.

Comment: Let's take the BRST quantisation method. From what I can tell, what we are really trying to impose is $\langle T_\alpha^\alpha\rangle_g = \langle T_\alpha^\alpha\rangle_{g'}$, where $g$, $g'$ are two different fixed metrics. To do so, we need the central charge, $c=0$. Suppose we take a different operator $O$, and compare $\langle O\rangle_g = \langle O\rangle_{g'}$, conserved current or otherwise. Then how do we know this doesn't give a different 'central charge' equivalent, which gives $D\neq 26$

Comment: The Weyl anomaly is explicitly computable, and we take it zero to guarantee Lorentz invariance. The second case you mention cannot happen. There are no [global symmetries in string theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26977/global-symmetry-in-string-theory) (see Motl's answer) nor local worldsheet symmetries because the worldsheet can always be taken locally flat, and no local invariants exist over Riemann surfaces. Such operators $O$ (charged with a possible anomalous symmetry) cannot exist in the worldsheet CFT.