# What is brane inflation, and can it be eternal?

Tags: cosmology, string-theory, cosmological-inflation, branes

What is Brane Inflation and how does it describe inflation process? Can it be eternal?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a a nice overview on the basics of brane inflation https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0610221 (see also https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0105203).

Brane inflation is, roughly speaking, a paradigm that propose an identification of brane/anti-brane annihilation processes with some types of cosmological inflation (typically hybrid ones).

Your question about the possibility of producing an eternal inflation scenario in the "brane inflation" paradigm cannot be answered unless you ask for a particular scenario within this paradigm.Despite of the later, I think is safe to say that in basic scenarios eternal inflation is not possible. The minimum of the potential for a tachyon field in a $D3$/ anti-$D3$-brane annihilation (in flat space) is reached at finite distances in moduli space, in other words, a stable vacuum for the pair is reached in finite time (see the review I attach).

Comment: But in KKLT scenarios, eternal inflation occurs.

Comment: That's not an established fact. In fact, many swampland criteria rule out the possibility of eternal inflation in the string theory landscape. See https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.07555 , https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.05198.pdf, https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.11106.  Although some loopholes on the latter arguments can be found, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.08943 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.11938. As I've said, it depends on what specific scenario you're asking for; in exactly the same way that happens in quantum field approaches to cosmological inflation.

Comment: It is far from the fact that the swampland criteria is correct

Comment: The point is that swampland criteria are much more well established than the KKLT and LV scenarios as full solutions of quantum gravity, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.01120.pdf. Also recall that there is no single example of fully reliable eternal inflation within string theory, in contrast, all known (tens of billions) string theory compactifications obey most swampland criteria.

Comment: To be fair, there is some pretty strong criticism of Swampland Criteria. The main argument is that the search for parameters is based on the "street lamp" principle. In addition, the cosmological constant is incompatible with the swamp and the quintessence models are poorly compatible.

Comment: I recommend that you familiarize yourself with last year's article by Vilenkin, which describes the possibility of eternal inflation even in the absence of de Sitter's vacuum. https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.00068

Comment: Of course, there are arguments against swampland criteria. But neither of them invalidate the fact (as I've said) that thousands of billions of string solutions obey them; some of those criteria can be actually proved, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26977/global-symmetry-in-string-theory or supported by roboust general arguments . That's strong evidence of their validity. Insted, no single example of sucessful eternal inflation exists in the literature.

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress Question: If you are so sure that eternal infation is a reliable possibility in the landscape and that swampland criteria are "weak", Why do you ask for the possibility of eternal inflation in brane-inflation scenarios?

Comment: If Swmapland is in such a strong position, then it definitely rejects eternal inflation. Why, then, doesn't science completely abandon the paradigm of eternal inflation?

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress Because swampland criteria are conjectures, conjectures supported by strong physical and statistical evidence, but still conjectures. Eternal inflation is a conjecture supported with zero solid evidence from the landscape. Actually most string theory leaders deny the possibility of eternal inflation in the landscape. I've shared papers with you that show that this is true.

Comment: By no means do I find the arguments for eternal inflation convincing; on the contrary, it seems to me that science needs to get rid of this misunderstanding as soon as possible. So I decided to check if it is still considered mainstream, or have scientists finally changed their minds and realized that this road leads nowhere?

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress That's good. Eternal inflation is no longer mainstream in the string cosmology literature, there are few papers with real (not just "string inspired") eternal inflation constructions. If you ask for the mainstream, the answer is: the swampland program and its implications is the mainstream.

Comment: What are the direct consequences of the swampland criteria for cosmology? Which models will be viable?

Comment: That's a really wonderful and enormous question. I'm not an expert, but I can comment that a consequence is that lots of models of inflation are in tension with swampland criteria. Simple, assisted and eternal scenarios are basically ruled out. But to my knowledge, simple models of hybrid inflation, such as the inspired by brane inflation are still a possibiity. I think that the same is true for more general slow-roll scenarios.  Unfortunately, I cannot tell nothing useful about the impact of the latter restrictions to the status of quintessence or phantom energy solutions.

Comment: I encourage you to post that question asking precisely for the particular aspect of cosmology that your'e interested in. 
It would be extremely interesting if someone could give an update on the viable models of inflation, for example.

Comment: Could it be that the swampland criteria turns out to be wrong assumptions?

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress Yes, absolutely. Especially the recent conjectures such as the trans-Planckian censorship one https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.11063 that are clearly less established.

Answer (score 0):

In String Cosmology, Brane inflation is a mathematical realisation of the Cosmic Inflation in the very early universe within the brane world framework. It usually depends on how the brane inflationary universe originated, eternal inflation of the false vacuum type is too possible. Eternal inflation of the false vacuum type inevitably happens in this case due to the tunneling process.

Comment: @Arman Armenpress, you can read the books on String Cosmology.

Comment: What is Brane World? 5-dimensional spacetime with 4-dimensional branes embedded in it?

Comment: No.............

Comment: What then? Can you tell me in general terms?

Comment: @SpinFoam Brane inflation is not restricted to brane-world scenarios, see https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0601099 for an example within a KKLT-like scenario.

Comment: Always or in some cases??

Comment: @SpinFoam Always. The building block of the KKLT construction is a special class of Calabi-Yau compactification. The brane world scenario (by definition) claim for a higher dimensional spacetime with all its dimensions uncompactified, something that does not hold in the KKLT or LV scenarios.

Comment: I just gave a general and a simpler answer.